# How to connect enable port to 4x1 MUX in verilog?

Tags: verilog

I am trying to implement 4x1 multiplexer in Verilog. I want to connect enable (**en**) as a port which input '1'(high) can ON the MUX and '0'(low) turn OFF this multiplexer.
Please suggest some modifications in my code.
Thanks in Advance.

```
module mux_4_to_1(
    input d,c,b,a,      //Inputs
    input s1,s0,               //Select Lines
    input en,                  //enable
    output reg y                   //output
    );

always @ (*)
begin
    case (s0 | s1)
    2'b00 : y <= a;
    2'b01 : y <= b;
    2'b10 : y <= c;
    2'b11 : y <= d;
    default : y <= 0;
    endcase
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `en` to act as a global switch to turn on or off the mux, so it gets the highest priority.

```
always @ (*)
begin
    if (en) begin
        case ({s0, s1})  // pay attention here
        2'b00 : y = a;
        2'b01 : y = b;
        2'b10 : y = c;
        2'b11 : y = d;
        default : y = 0;
        endcase
    end
    else begin
        y = 1'b0;  // your question didn't specify the expected output when OFF
    end
end
```

Please notice I've changed `case (s0 | s1)` to `case ({s0, s1})`.
`s0 | s1` returns a 1-bit wide result, while you need the concatenation of `s0` and `s1`.

Also, I replaced all NBA `<=` by BA `=`.

And, the `default` branch actually couldn't happen in silicon because you've specified all possible combinations. But if you think it maybe helpful in simulation, you may leave it.